# DIV inside DIV inside DIV 100% Height

Tags: css-float

I know this question has probably been asked before and I have tried several different ways of doing this, but I can not seem to get my inner DIV to expand to the full height of the viewport.

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; height: auto !important; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;}

p, h1 {font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;text-align:left;margin:1em 0}

 /*******************************************************************************
Primary Container Structure
********************************************************************************/
#container {width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px; background-color: #fff; color: #333;}

#top {padding: .5em; background-color: #3b5998; color:White;}
#top h1 {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

#subcontainer {width: 90%; margin: 0px auto; line-height: 130%;}

#rightnav {height:100%; float: right; width: 244px; margin: 0; padding: 1em; max-width:244px;}
#content {height:100%; border-left: 1px solid gray; margin-right: 284px; border-right: 1px solid gray; padding: 1em;}

#leftnav p, #rightnav p {margin: 0 0 1em 0;}
#content h2 {margin: 0 0 .5em 0;}

#footer {clear: both; margin: 0; padding: .5em; color: #333; background-color: #ddd; border-top: 1px solid gray;}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SHELL.aspx.cs" Inherits="SHELL" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">  

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="container">

    <div id="top">
        <h1>NAME</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="subcontainer">



        <div id="rightnav">
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h2>Subheading</h2>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
            </p>
            <p>
            Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
            </p>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean the id="content" div doesn't expand to the height of the browser, such that footer is at the bottom of your browser?

Comment: Which 'inner div' do you want to be 100%? #content?

Comment: I want id=content to fill the screen and push the id=footer to the bottom of the screen. It does not do it in IE or Firefox right now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a middle container first calculate a footer height, then subtract it from it's 100% height parent container.

You're only options with your current markup are:

1. Use javascript (unncessary overhead)
2. Use tables (probably not a good idea)
3. Here is an option that I had to rearrange your code: [Code Here](https://gist.github.com/904771)

I made your height and footer work, but it will require you to use [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), a common technique for bottom sticking footers.  See [this](http://www.savio.no/examples/three-column-layout-6.asp) for an example.

Simply, assign a left border image to repeat-y on the body, and a right border image to repeat-y, background right, on the subcontainer.